# How to architect HTTP error handlers in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, middleware, http-status-codes

what will be the best architecture or pattern to handle the HTTP error code in express js, so that it can be handle from one place irrespective of the diffferent boiler plates.

Currently i'm handling it with the middleware.

that's Middleware code

```
// Error Handler
app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
    res.status(err.httpStatusCode).json(err)
})
```

while triggering it with this through controller :

```
(async ()=>{

                            var savedUser = await newUser.save();
                            if(savedUser.id){

                                resolve({
                                    success:'ok',
                                    email : savedUser.email,
                                    fullname: savedUser.personal.fullname,
                                    activation : savedUser.activation
                                });

                            }else{
                                reject({success:'no'}) 
                            }   


                        })().catch((err)=>{
                            err.httpStatusCode = 500
                            return next(err)
                        })
```

Comment: How are you handling errors now? Share your code.

Comment: @Shumail i have added the code please check